Python cannot connect to the Exchange mail server
Good day.
I have a problem when I write a Python script to connect to my work mailbox on Microsoft Outlook Web (OWA). Version OS of mailserver is 'Microsoft Windows NT 6.0.6003 Service Pack 2'.
I do not have administrator rights to access this mailbox. I only have a username, password, and mail server address.
I can freely access this mailbox from any phone or web browser.But when I try to connect to this mailbox using a Python script with exchangelib, I get error "connection failed".
I tried using the 'exchangelib' library.
Below is a piece of my code.
    import exchangelib
    from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials, Message, Mailbox, HTMLBody, Configuration
    creds = Credentials (username = 'usernam@workdomain.**', password = 'pass')
    config = Configuration (credentials = creds, server = 'https://owa.workdomain.**', \
    service_endpoint = None, auth_type = 'basic', version = None, retry_policy = None, max_connections = None)
    account = Account(primary_smtp_address = 'usernam@workdomain.**',fullname = 'usernam',\
     access_type = DELEGATE, autodiscover = False, \
    credentials = creds, config = config, locale = None, default_timezone = None)

And I get this error:
    raise TransportError(f"No valid version headers found in response ({e!r})")
    exchangelib.errors.TransportError: 
    No valid version headers found in response #(ErrorTimeoutExpired('Reraised from ConnectionError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): 
    Max retries exceeded #with url: /owa.*******.**/EWS/Exchange.asmx (Caused by #NameResolutionError
    ("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at #0x000001EDF67CBC10>: 
    Failed to resolve 'https' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

I see that there is an error in the version of the request header, but I do not understand how to #fix it.
If I use argument 'autodiscover=True', I get this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", 
    line 179, in init self.ad_response, self.protocol = Autodiscovery( 
    File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", 
    line 124, in discover ad = self._step_1(hostname=domain) 
    File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", 
    line 336, in _step_1 return self._step_2(hostname=hostname) 
    File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", 
    line 352, in _step_2 return self._step_3(hostname=hostname) 
    File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", 
    line 388, in _step_3 return self._step_4(hostname=hostname) 
    File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", 
    line 415, in _step_4 return self._step_6() 
    File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", 
    line 467, in _step_6 raise AutoDiscoverFailed( exchangelib.errors.
    AutoDiscoverFailed: 
    All steps in the autodiscover protocol failed for email myusername@workdomain.xx. 
    If you think this is an error, consider doing an official test at 
    https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com

I'm trying to get the last 10 emails I received. With this script.
    import exchangelib 
    import pytz
    from exchangelib import DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, Account,  Credentials, \
    EWSDateTime, EWSTimeZone, Configuration, NTLM, GSSAPI, CalendarItem,\
     Message, Mailbox, Attendee, Q, ExtendedProperty, FileAttachment, ItemAttachment, \
     HTMLBody, Build, Version, FolderCollection
    credentials = Credentials(username='workdomain.xx\\myusername', password ='xxxxxxx')
    version = Version(build=Build(8,3,83,0))
    config = Configuration(service_endpoint = 'https://owa.workdomain.xx', \
    credentials = credentials, version = version, auth_type = NTLM)
    account = Account (primary_smtp_address = 'myusername@workdomain.xx', config = config, \
    autodiscover = False, access_type = DELEGATE)
    inbox = account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:10]
    for message in inbox:
        print(message.subject)

But I still can't even log in to my mailbox.((
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\cached_property.py", line 70, in __get__
        return obj_dict[name]
     KeyError: 'inbox'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\cached_property.py", line 70, in __get__
        return obj_dict[name]
    KeyError: 'root'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\xxxxxx.py", line 22, in <module>
        inbox = account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:10]
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\cached_property.py", line 74, in __get__
       return obj_dict.setdefault(name, self.func(obj))
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", line 286, in inbox
        return self.root.get_default_folder(Inbox)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\cached_property.py", line 74, in __get__
        return obj_dict.setdefault(name, self.func(obj))
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", line 350, in root
        return Root.get_distinguished(account=self)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\roots.py", line 145, in get_distinguished
        return cls._get_distinguished(
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\base.py", line 226, in _get_distinguished
        return cls.resolve(account=folder.account, folder=folder)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\base.py", line 530, in resolve
        folders = list(FolderCollection(account=account,         folders=[folder]).resolve())
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\collections.py", line 335, in resolve
yield from self.__class__(account=self.account,        folders=resolveable_folders).get_folders(
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\collections.py", line 403, in get_folders
yield from GetFolder(account=self.account).call(
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\get_folder.py", line 51, in _elems_to_objs
        for folder, elem in zip(self.folders, elems):
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 279, in _chunked_get_elements
        yield from self._get_elements(payload=payload_func(chunk, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 309, in _get_elements
        self._handle_backoff(e)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 438, in _handle_backoff
raise e
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 300, in _get_elements
yield from self._response_generator(payload=payload)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 263, in _response_generator
        response = self._get_response_xml(payload=payload)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 396, in _get_response_xml
        r = self._get_response(payload=payload, api_version=api_version)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py", line 347, in _get_response
r, session = post_ratelimited(
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\util.py", line 866, in post_ratelimited
protocol.retry_policy.raise_response_errors(r)
      File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\protocol.py", line 704, in raise_response_errors
raise ErrorServerBusy("Caused by closed connection")
   exchangelib.errors.ErrorServerBusy: Caused by closed connection


The server argument is supposed to be just a hostname. If you want to use a URL, then use the service_endpoint argument instead. You need to use the URL that hosts the server's EWS webservice, not OWA. Finally, if autodiscover is setup for your email address, then just use that instead to find the correct server to connect to.

Thanks for the reaction.
I tried to enable autodiscover but I still can't connect to the server.  I get this error.
File "C:\Python 3.9.13\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", line 467, in _step_6
raise AutoDiscoverFailed(
exchangelib.errors.AutoDiscoverFailed: All steps in the autodiscover protocol failed for email myusername@workdomain.xx. If you think this is an error, consider doing an official test at https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question!
I changed the "server" argument to "service_endpoint" because I only have URL-address of OWA server. I do not have any additional details of the EWS service.
Did I do everything right from what you recommended to me?

but I still  can't connection to the server.  I added error text to the general topic

So, did an official test at the mentioned website succeed or fail?

If you can't use autodiscover, then you need to ask your Exchange server admins for the correct EWS endpoint and the supported authentication methods.

It looks like I'll have to ask the admin for additional login details.
I wonder why I can log into my mailbox through any mail application, on any android smartphone, but the Python script can't do it?
Maybe the settings on the EWS side do not give authentication to any Python scripts?

Maybe those clients don't use EWS? Still, the errors above indicate that you're not contacting the right endpoint that hosts the EWS webservice. And it's still not clear whether autodiscover is supposed to work on your email domain. Do the clients that work use autodiscover?
